# TreeView for mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, treeview

I am trying to display my data in form of a treeview in a MVC 4 application. But I am very new in MVC, so maybe somebody could recommend some step-by-step tutorial on how to use such a treeview with MVC 4?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no "ready to use" control like that in MVC. You should use a Jquery plugin for that.

Take a look in here:

UPDATED LINK:

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-treeview/

Comment: Thank, I have seen this already. But as I said, I need a detailed step-by-step tutorial, if such a tutorial exists.

Comment: I found a step by step guide. Take a look and if you'll have any problems comment in here again, and I'll try to help you.

http://weblogs.asp.net/mikebosch/archive/2008/11/25/hierarchical-treeview-with-asp-net-mvc-jquery.aspx

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising. But it doesn't look like speaking about mvc 4 projects, as it mentions code-behind etc...

Comment: @DavidShochet this last link (http://weblogs.asp.net/mikebosch/archive/2008/11/25/hierarchical-treeview-with-asp-net-mvc-jquery.aspx) is Jquery and MVC. It uses MVC 2, but you'll only change the code in your View to Razor Synthax. (Replace "%" to "@" )

Comment: Yeah, I saw the answer was a litte old.  I was just trying to help out and let you know.  I thought you might want to either update the link or remove it.

Comment: All questions related to mvc and treeviews are suggesting this dead link, does anyone know new location or a similar guide?

Comment: @EgeBayrak just fixed the answer with the new link.

Answer (score 1):

I end up using below with my MVC 4 project and it works a treat,

https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-treeview

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem.

As Thiago Custodio already mentioned, there is no standard control for this with .net mvc4

My solution is to use the html list tags < ul > and < li > which can also include nesting. And then apply some styling wih css. if you want I can post an example. I used jquery on the ul to hide/show the inner li

Cheerz, David

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display data in tree view structure then I have written custom code which you can use directly. If you are interested then please reply me I will give you that code.

only you need to replace your content in that & its three level